# How to translate this Math Formula in Haskell or Python? (Was translated in PHP)

Tags: php, python, math, haskell, matrix

I'm trying to convert a Math Formula into PHP code.

You can see the formula in the accepted answer here: [Applying a Math Formula in a more elegant way (maybe a recursive call would do the trick)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/92942/applying-a-math-formula-in-a-more-elegant-way-maybe-a-recursive-call-would-do-t).

I'm not a professional coder so I'm trying my best to translate it but my skills are limited and I've encountered several problems.

Let's start.

There's a vector containing players' stacks: I think a bidimensional array should do the work here. I'd add a key to identify each player.

```
$array = array(1 => 2000, 3 => 5000 ...);
```

Now he wants to create a Matrix of values, I did my researches and found a PEAR package called Math_Matrix, installed it but I'm wondering how to create that sort of matrix.

I'm worried that I won't be able to translate the entire code because he uses advances methods like recursive calls etc.

Could you help me?

*EDIT: OLD BOUNTY REWARD*

I tried what you've suggested but I feel like wasting my time because of my poor-programming skills.

I'VE DECIDED TO OFFER A 50 BOUNTY IF SOMEONE WANTS TO HELP ME BY TRANSLATING THAT FORMULA IN PHP.

Note that if you think that translating in Python is easier/more suitable/other, please provide me a way to include the Python script inside a PHP script since I'm planning to use this formula in a website.

Comment: all I can say is WOW..... This is some serious math into a non math oriented programming language.

Comment: Do you think someone could solve this in PHP?

Comment: Or which language that I can implement in PHP can be used to solve this?

Comment: I am saying I dont know if it is or isnt possible to be solved in PHP. I would lean to say it most likely is possible. But there are other programming languages such as Haskell and Python(I know I am missing some others here these are just the ones I know) which are much better number and math oriented languages. I would suppose also that the solution in PHP maybe long and would run slowly.

Comment: An array of arrays could also be seen as a matrix. It's actually how most calculators, libraries, etc. implement it.

Comment: mmm... array of array? Could work to store values in form of a matrix. Matybe the problem will come when shifting values and performing other matrix operations.

Comment: Don't edit an old question to include a new question.  Ask a new question instead.

Comment: Oh sorry! I didn't know that!!

Comment: I thought it was more appropriate to edit the question since it's basically the same.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here you go.

I place this code into the public domain.

```
# Function to make an array of 'width' zeros
function makerow($width){
 $row=array();
 for($x=0;$x<$width;$x++){
   $row[$x]=0;
 }
 return $row;
}

# Function to make a width*height matrix
function makematrix($width,$height){
 $matrix=array();
 for($y=0;$y<$height;$y++){
  $matrix[$y]=array();
  for($x=0;$x<$width;$x++){
   $matrix[$y][$x]=0;
  }
 }
 return $matrix;
}

# Adds one matrix to another
function matrixadd(&$matrixdest,&$matrixsrc){
 for($i=0;$i<count($matrixdest);$i++){
  for($j=0;$j<count($matrixdest[$i]);$j++){
   $matrixdest[$i][$j]+=$matrixsrc[$i][$j];
  }
 }
}

# Multiplies a matrix by a scalar
function matrixmultiply(&$matrix,$scalar){
 for($i=0;$i<count($matrix);$i++){
  for($j=0;$j<count($matrix[$i]);$j++){
   $matrix[$i][$j]*=$scalar;
  }
 }
}

# Calculates the equity of each place. Rows indicate players;
# columns indicate places (0 is 1st place, 1 is second, and so on)
# The parameter 'places' is optional.  If not given, uses the 
# number of stacks.
function equitymatrix(&$stacks, $places=-1){
 if($places==-1){
  # replace places with the stack count
  $places=count($stacks);
 }
 if(count($stacks)<=1){
  return array(array(1));
 }  
 $totalStacks=0;
 for($i=0;$i<count($stacks);$i++){
  $totalStacks+=$stacks[$i];
 }
 # Optimize for case where there is only one place
 if($places==1){
  $matrix=makematrix(1,count($stacks));
  for($i=0;$i<count($stacks);$i++){
   $matrix[$i][0]=$stacks[$i]*1.0/$totalStacks;
  }
  return $matrix;
 }
 # Optimize for case where there are two places
 if($places==2){
  $matrix=makematrix(2,count($stacks));
  for($i=0;$i<count($stacks);$i++){
   $matrix[$i][0]=$stacks[$i]*1.0/$totalStacks;
  }
  for($i=0;$i<count($stacks);$i++){
   for($j=0;$j<count($stacks);$j++){
    if($i!=$j){
     $matrix[$i][1]+=$matrix[$j][0]*($stacks[$i]*1.0/($totalStacks-$stacks[$j]));
    }
   }
  }
  return $matrix;
 }
 # Calculate the probabilities of each player getting first place
 $probabilities=array();
 for($i=0;$i<count($stacks);$i++){
  $probabilities[$i]=$stacks[$i]*1.0/$totalStacks;
 }
 #echo(count($stacks)." ".$places."\n");
 $subequities=array();
 for($i=0;$i<count($stacks);$i++){
  $substacks=array();
  # Assume that player i would be in first place
  # Create a new array with i's stack removed
  for($j=0;$j<count($stacks);$j++){
   if($j!=$i){
    array_push($substacks,$stacks[$j]);
   }
  }
  # Find the subequity of the remaining players
  $subequities[$i]=equitymatrix($substacks,
    min($places,count($substacks)));
  for($j=0;$j<count($subequities[$i]);$j++){
   array_unshift($subequities[$i][$j],0);
  }
  # Add player i back
  $newrow=makerow($places);
  $newrow[0]=1;
  array_splice($subequities[$i],$i,0,array($newrow));
 }
 $equities=makematrix($places,count($stacks));
 for($i=0;$i<count($stacks);$i++){
  # Multiply the probabilities
  matrixmultiply($subequities[$i],$probabilities[$i]);
  # Add the subequity
  matrixadd($equities,$subequities[$i]);
 }
 return $equities;
}
```

Example:

```
$mystacks=array(10,40,30,20);
print_r(equitymatrix($mystacks));
```

---

As to the use of matrices:

In PHP, a matrix can be represented as an array of arrays.  You can see
that in the function `makematrix`, which returns an array of length `height`,
with each element being an array of `width` zeros.  Your problem uses the following
matrix operations, both of which are simple:

- Adding two matrices (`matrixadd`).  Here, just add the elements of one matrix to the
  corresponding elements of the other matrix.
- Multiplying a matrix by a single number (a scalar) (`matrixmultiply`) simply 
  involves multiplying each element of the matrix by that number.

Comment: I've analyzed your code and it's awsome! :)
The only problem is in the math algorithm itself: too slow.

Is it possible to speed up the code by calculating only a determined number of equity on places?

I mean: in a scenario where there are 6 players, the code above would calculate the equity of every player on each place till the 6th place. 
If we need only their equity on 1st and 2nd place can we skip the remanent code, can't we?

It would be useful to have something like print_r(equitymatrix($mystacks,2));
Where the number stays for the places we wanna calculate the equity on.

Comment: I've edited the code in my answer to add an extra parameter, as you suggested, and to add optimizations in the case where one or two places are desired. However, it's difficult to optimize this solution for more than two places, as the complexity scales with the number of *players*, not with the number of desired places.

Comment: I've awarded yours as the accepted answer and credited you with the 50 rep bonus. Thanks for your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the biggest question is what you plan to use this for. In the end I would really recommend against using PHP. Its not designed for this type of work and you'll end up causing a lot of work for yourself later.

If you are just looking for a means of calculating it, I would recommend using Octave (The OpenSource Version of MATLAB) If you actually want to build a program around it, you should look into Python using the NumPy module: [Link](https://numpy.org/)

---

If you have the ability, I would recommend using mod_python for running NumPy to handle this. It would likely be the simplest means of doing it as NumPy can natively handle Matrices. Barring that, you should look at the following classes that exist for handling matrices in PHP. Some individuals have developed some classes designed specifically for manipulating Matrices.

http://www.phpkode.com/scripts/item/matrix-new/
http://www.phpclasses.org/package/2859-PHP-Perform-operations-with-matrices.html

Comment: I'd like to create a website like this one: http://www.icmpoker.com/Calculator.aspx
It appears to use a similar algorithm to calculates equities.

Comment: Went ahead and added some more information specific to what you are after along with some links to classes designed specifically for Matrix Math in PHP. I still think Python would handle it better, but its a little more difficult to implement depending on the control you have over your webhost.

Comment: Thank you man, I'll do some researches to achieve this in PHP because I don't know Python and implementing it in a website should make it even more complex...

Answer (score 0):

If you have Matlab installed, with the symbolic math toolbox,

you can use the `ccode` function in order to translate this formula (or any other) to c-code (which is very similar to php).